# Как в CSS двигать div со всем содержимым внутри?

Tags: css, css3

Как в `CSS` двигать **div** со всем содержимым внутри? Если создать `div`, а внутри например форму, то при перемещении `div` двигается только сам `div`, но не то что внутри. Как двигать `div` вместе с содержимым? Вот [HTML](https://pastebin.com/vxgH3kvA), а вот [CSS](https://pastebin.com/n2MVXeyu).

Comment: Где ваш волшебный код?

Comment: вот HTML pastebin.com/vxgH3kvA вот CSS pastebin.com/n2MVXeyu. там серый div идет как основной который нужно двигать что бы со всем содержимым.

Comment: Код необходимо выкладывать в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте родительскому `div`, который будете двигать `position` отличный от `static` в зависимости от ситуации:

```
position: relative;
```

или

```
position: absolute;
```

или например

```
position: fixed;
```

*p.s. без примеров кода, можно строить только догадки относительно ответа на ваш вопрос.*

Answer (score 0):

Родителю поставить position:relative, потомку поставить position:absolute